# Insalling Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to create a ubuntu bootable USB disk [using this site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu.).

I have downloaded Ubuntu 64 bit Desktop version to my Windows 7 PC . It shows up as 'ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64' winRAR application.

The instructions say to 'Open the dash and search for StartupDiskCreator'. I have searched and thankfully I understood dash means the menu.  But where is this menu shown ?

Should  I use a utility to run the 'ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64' file instead of extracting using WinRAR?

Will I then be able to see the 'dash/menu'?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you do not have Ubuntu installed on your machine, you only have the ISO file downloaded to your computer. The dash is a part of Unity, and is only accessible once you install Ubuntu. If you want the flash drive without the mess of having another operating system installed, I suggest you use a VirtualBox guest and create a startup disk that way.